# execute function when iframe changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm building a function that accepts credit card payments with an iframe. The problem I'm dealing with right now is that there are some errors that appear differently, in a very 'ugly' way.
Photo: http://i63.tinypic.com/jtqu6p.png
I've been trying to capture the iframe's OnLoad or OnChange events, but none of them have worked so far.

HTML:

```
<div id="iframe-container"></div>
```

Javascript:
For corporate reasons, I can't show the code, this is all I can offer:
I have an < iframe id="iframe-to-send" >, which i append to the #iframe-container.
I hope it's enough.

Things I've tried:
Javascript:

```
window.onload=function() {
    load()
}

function load() {
    repeat = setTimeout(load, 1000);
    try {
        var str = document.getElementById("result-message").innerHTML;
        if (str == "") {
            console.log("function if true");
            clearTimeout(repeat);
        } else {
            console.log("function if false" + " --- " + "str: " + str);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Caught error: ' + err)
    }
}
```

With this code, I kept getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" since the message I'm trying to compare is loaded after submitting payment info.

PS: I know I'm comparing with "", it's just a testcase.

Afterwards, I attempted multiple instances of onchange and onload with the #iframe-to-send and #iframe-container, but none of those worked.

HTML:

```
<div id="iframe-container" onchange="console.log('Works!');"></div>
```

and

```
<div id="iframe-container" onload="console.log('Works!');"></div>
```

I tried those 2 just to see if in one of the cases, I'll get the "Works!", and didn't.

I'm quite unexperienced in this area, so it could easily be something very simple that I've missed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the iframed page and the parent page from the same origin?

Comment: @Terry I misunderstood your question. They're not, the parent page is ours and the iframe is an addon.

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery to get the frame load using the following code.

```
<script>
jQuery('#myframe').ready(function () {
                 alert('frame is loaded');
            });
</script>
```

Comment: This works, but only when it loads for the very first time. What I need is exactly this, but after I've entered my payment info and submit the form. Just as the error appears.